# merge lines of text with user input in second line

Tags: python

How do I make the user input print on the same line as prior text?

```
print('Enter the rainfall amount for month', months, end='')
monthly_rainfall=float(input(': '))
```

Desired result:

```
Enter the rainfall amount for month 1: 1
```

---

Actual result:

```
Enter the rainfall amount for month 1
: 1
```

Comment: It works for me

Comment: hm something in my Spyder settings then maybe..

Comment: It also works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `input()` instead. This should give you a much more simple solution.

```
monthly_rainfall = float(input('Enter rainfall amount for month {0}: '.format(months)))
```

Comment: thank you! works for me. not sure why the original does not work for me